# Why is my EC2 server's time off by ~10 seconds every day?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, synchronization, time

I have what I believe is a system file, `/etc/cron.daily/ntpupdate` which runs 
 `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` daily to sync with the network time. Every day it generates output very similar to this:

```
/etc/cron.daily/ntpupdate:
16 Jan 06:30:42 ntpdate[21446]:
step time server 91.189.94.4 offset -12.646804 sec
```

I'm not positive what the `91.189.94.4` means but I'm pretty sure `-12.646804 sec` means that my server is off by around 12 seconds. But I don't know why it is off by around the same amount every day. This is an Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu.

I can only guess that either it is losing / gaining 12 seconds per day, or something else is syncing the time with another clock that is off by 12 seconds and then I am re-syncing it.

What should I do to try and track this down further? I don't see any other cron jobs in the `/etc/cron.*` directories or in the users' cron jobs...

**UPDATE**

Just thought I'd share that I started running this hourly to see if there would be a big jump at a certain hour. This is what the hourly output is:

```
16 Jan 15:17:04 ntpdate[8346]:
adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.464418 sec
```

So apparently every hour the clock is off by around half a second, so that makes sense that each day (24 hours) the clock would be off by around 12 seconds. Guess the clock is just running fast! Thanks!

Comment: 91.189.94.4 is ntp.ubuntu.com's IP address

Comment: follow this link. Your issue will be resolved. It helped to solve the same issue
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a number of factors that might make a software clock run slow or fast. Clocks on virtual servers are especially prone to a whole class of these problems. 12 seconds a day is pretty bad until you come across virtual boxes with clocks that run at 180–200% speed! Clocks on laptops that suspend can suffer from time-keeping issues too.

You should consider dropping `ntupdate` in favour of `ntpd`. The package name is `ntp` on Debian (and presumably Ubuntu too). The NTP daemon keeps your time in sync a lot more proactively than a cron job, synchronising with one or more other NTP servers and keeping your clock much more accurate. It's another implementation of the same protocol `ntpdate` uses, except `ntpd` monitors the time continuously.

If you don't want the (very small) overhead of `ntpd`, you might consider running `ntpdate` once an hour. Assuming you're 0.5s off every hour, that should be sufficient.

Comment: The virtual machine issues can also be largely resolved by running a tickless kernel (CONFIG_NO_HZ). Not sure if this is possible with ubuntu kernel, or if you'd have to build your own.

Comment: I just checked the kernel config on an Ubuntu 11 installation (3.0.0-14-generic), and it definitely has `CONFIG_NO_HZ` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the other half of your question, on why this is happening: Computer hardware clocks are notoriously inaccurate, so while a drift of 12 seconds in a day is unusual, it's not really all that unusual.

(This is probably because of the prevalence of usage of network time, so that a drift of even 12 seconds a day is a minor annoyance compared to what it would be in a watch -- and thus the hardware companies can use cheap clock chips.  Physically, what's happening is probably that the oscillator in your clock chip isn't calibrated quite right, so it runs slightly-but-reliably slow.)

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that ntp does not update your server's time because the difference is too small. I had a similar problem, I saw the same delay every day, until I found out that being a little difference ntp would not update until a specific threshold is present.

Check you configuration for minimum threshold for sync.

Comment: This is not true. On the contrary, NTP attempts to reduce the difference as much as it can. There is a threshold in the other direction: NTP won't update the clock if the difference is too large (it suspects a misconfiguration, e.g. wrong timezone).